# MongoDB error while picking random documents via Spring Data repository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface GooglePlayGamesRepository extends MongoRepository <GooglePlayGame, String> {

    GooglePlayGame findByTitleIgnoreCase(String gameTitle);

    @Query("{$sample: {size: ?0} }")
    List<GooglePlayGame> findRandomGames(Long amount);
}
```

And want to get random documents from my db:

```
private String getFollowingRandomGames(Long numberOfGames) {
   return googlePlayGamesRepository.findRandomGames(getNumberOfGames()).stream()
           .map(GooglePlayGame::getTitle)
           .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

But I get following error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $sample' on server ...; 
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException
```

Comment: [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/index.html) is an Aggregation stage. Try using the `@Aggregation` instead of `@Query`.